# Count negative numbers using array and while loop

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, counter

Have an assignment and am new to this. The assignment is to count the negative numbers in a given array, and to print out the amount they are counted. And I have to use a while loop. I am getting a lot of errors.

```
class NegativeNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] wholeNumber = {1, 4, 5, -2, -4, 6, 10, 3, -2};
        int counter = 0;
        int negativeCounter = 0;
        int sum;

        while(counter < wholeNumber.length) {
           sum = sum + wholeNumber;
           if(wholeNumber < 0)
           {
             negativeCounter++;
           }
          }
          System.out.println("The amount of negative numbers are "+negativeCounter);
   }
}
```

Comment: "a lot of errors"...please tell us what those errors are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 while(counter < wholeNumber.length) {
       if(wholeNumber[counter] < 0)
       {
         sum += wholeNumber[counter];
         negativeCounter++;
       }
      counter++
      }
```

Comment: Hint: you are kinda lucky that your answer go accepted; as there are several **better** answers than yours around. You didn't even put down an explanation!

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
if(wholeNumber < 0)
```

to

```
if(wholeNumber[counter] < 0)
```

and

```
sum = sum + wholeNumber;
```

to

```
sum = sum + wholeNumber[counter];
```

**or** the shorter

```
sum += wholeNumber[counter];
```

and don't forget to increment `counter` at the end of your loop body

```
counter++;
```

#### Or, in Java 8+

You could use [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html)

```
int[] wholeNumber = { 1, 4, 5, -2, -4, 6, 10, 3, -2 };
int sum = IntStream.of(wholeNumber).sum();
long negativeCount = IntStream.of(wholeNumber).filter(x -> x < 0).count();
System.out.printf("%s Sum=%d, Count=%d%n", 
        Arrays.toString(wholeNumber), sum, negativeCount);
```

Answer (score 2):

You must use wholeCounter[counter] and increment counter at the end

Answer (score 2):

1. Sum is an int value;
2. WholeNumber is an array;
3. "+" operater doesn't support the addition between int and array. You need use the index of the array to get an int value.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:

```
public class NegativeNumber {
```

Your class must be **public** when you want to later run its **main** method!

Your loop can be simplified, using the **for each** style of for loops:

```
    for (int number : wholeNumber } {
       sum = sum + number;
       if(number < 0)  {
         negativeCounter++;
       }
    }
```

And hint: wholeNumber is a misleading name for an array. Why not call it wholeNumber**s** instead?! To express the fact that this variable is about numbers in plural!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily using for loop

```
public class NegativeNum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int[] wholeNumber = {1, 4, 5, -2, -4, 6, 10, 3, -2};

        int negativeCounter = 0;
        int sum=0;

        for(int i =0; i<wholeNumber.length; i++)
        {
            if(wholeNumber[i]< 0)
            {
                sum =sum+ wholeNumber[i];
                negativeCounter++;
            }

        }
        System.out.println(sum + " " + negativeCounter);
    }

}
```